# Return to next tabindex after posting back

Tags: javascript, ajax

My user is presented with generic names: name1, name2, name3 and is asked to change each to more meaningful names. How can I make the ajax post return go to the next input/tabindex or at least not return to the name just changed? (Look for `WHAT GOES HERE?` comment below)

HTML:

```
    <div class="name"><input type="text" id="nameinput1" value="name1" onchange="changeName(0)"></div>
    <div class="name"><input type="text" id="nameinput2" value="name2" onchange="changeName(1)"></div>
    <div class="name"><input type="text" id="nameinput3" value="name3" onchange="changeName(2)"></div>
```

javascript:

```
    var jsons = '[{' ;
    var jsone = '"}]' ;
    function changeName(index){
    var json = jsons;
    var name = document.getElementById("main").getElementsByTagName("input")[index].value;
                json += '"index":"'+index+'",'
                json += '"name":"'+name.replace(/\s/g,"")+jsone
                loadDoc(json,"ID","url",returnChangeName)
            }       
    function returnChangeName(xttp){
    window.location = "#";    //  WHAT GOES HERE?
}            
    loadDoc(...){....}
```

Pure javascript, no jquery, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to pass the current index to the callback function `returnChangeName` and you can get the next input in the callback. I also recommend you using the `JSON.stringify` function for converting objects to string:

```
function changeName(index) {
    var name = document.getElementById("main").getElementsByTagName("input")[index].value;
    var json = [{
        index: index,
        name: name.replace(/\s/g, "")
    }];
    loadDoc(JSON.stringify(json), "ID", "url", returnChangeName(index));
}

function returnChangeName(index) {
    return function returnChangeNameResponse(xttp) {
        var next = document.getElementById("main").getElementsByTagName("input")[index + 1];
        if (next) {
            // whatever you want to do with this
            // for example, focus the next one
            next.focus();
        }
    }
}

function loadDoc(json, id, url, callback) {
    // sth
    callback({});
}
```